# How to extract complete function information on LLVM?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to

1. extract functions' LLVM IR
2. save each of them to a different file (or just a string object)
3. read the saved function from the file (or just a string object)
4. re-use it on the framework

However, my current extraction approach only copies partial information and I cannot re-build the function afterwards. I mainly have problems with IR Reader complaining about:

```
error: use of undefined type named 'class.std::allocator'
...
error: use of undefined comdat '$_ZNSt10_Iter_baseIPiLb0EE7_S_baseES0_'
```

Which it is possible to work around by adding proper declarations (comdat and type) to the top of extracted IR.

BEFORE:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define linkonce_odr i64 @_ZNK9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8max_sizeEv(%"class.__gnu_cxx::new_allocator"*) #4 comdat align 2 {
  ret i64 4611686018427387903
}
```

AFTER:

```
%"class.__gnu_cxx::new_allocator" = type { i8 }
$_ZNK9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8max_sizeEv = comdat any

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define linkonce_odr i64 @_ZNK9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8max_sizeEv(%"class.__gnu_cxx::new_allocator"*) #4 comdat align 2 {
  ret i64 4611686018427387903
}
```

I am currently implementing steps 1,2,3,4 by using the following:

```
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/StringRef.h"
#include "llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h" // SMDDiagnostic
#include "llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h"

using namespace llvm;

...

// A method receives a LLVM::Function& F as its argument
// Steps 1 and 2
std::string IRString;
raw_string_ostream os(IRString);
F.print(os, nullptr);
os.flush();

// IRString has the LLVM IR for the function (currently with the BEFORE version)
// Now it is necessary to read back this IR
// Steps 3 and 4
SMDiagnostic Err;
LLVMContext Context;
std::unique_ptr<llvm::MemoryBuffer> buff =
llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(SU.getIRInfo());

std::unique_ptr<Module> Mod(parseIR(buff->getMemBufferRef(), Err, Context));
if (!Mod) {
    Err.print("Reading Problems", errs());
    return 1;
}

...
```

How can I make this process automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at llvm-extract or GVExtraction class (which is used by llvm-extract).